# How to add ref to button in a HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-field-uctfd?file=/src/App.js

I have a component that returns a button:

`const Button = props => <button ref={?} style={{ color: props.color }}>bt</button>;`

I am trying to understand HOCs and refForwarding. This is a HOC a Component:

```
const colorer = Button => {
  const ButtontWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <Button {...props} ref={ref} />;
  });
  class Colored extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <ButtonWithRef color="red" ref={this.props.passedRef} />;
    }
  }
  return Colored;
};
```

The colored button that is used in components:

`const Colored = colorer(Button);`

I am trying to access the `button` inside `Button` component using `ref`. But I don't know how to forward `ref` when the `Button` is passed through a HOC(`colorer`). When I console.log the `ref` I get

`Object {current: null}`

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  const myRef = React.createRef();
  console.log(myRef);
  return (<Colored passedRef={myRef} />);
}
```

How do I set the `ref` to the actual `button` inside `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button component can make use of `forwardRef` and pass on the `ref` to the actual button component

```
const Button = React.forwardRef(
      (props, ref) => <button ref={ref} style={{ color: props.color }}>bt</button>
);
```

---

The rest of the code will remain the same except inside App component you would make use of `useRef` instead of `React.createRef` since App is a functional component

```
const colorer = Button => {
  const ButtontWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <Button {...props} ref={ref} />;
  });
  class Colored extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <ButtonWithRef color="red" ref={this.props.passedRef} />;
    }
  }
  return Colored;
};

...
export default function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(myRef);
  return (<Colored passedRef={myRef} />);
}
```

Comment: how to colorize and use it in App.js

Comment: @Abhi you entire workflow apart from the button component will remain the same. You would make use of colorer hoc and wrap Button component in it